# Overlaps method won't work

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm using libGDX to create a game like curve fever but for Android.
Actually I'm working on the collision but everything I try won't work; I use the `overlaps` methods from the `Rectangle` class.
It always returns `false`.

Here's the code which checks if there's a collision:

```
public void collision() {
    if(head.getAlive()) {
        for (TailSnake tail : getTail()) {
            if (tail.lifeTime > 2)
                if (head.bounds.overlaps(tail.bounds))
                    head.dead();
        }
        for (Object wallObj : getWall()) {
            Wall wall = (Wall) wallObj;
            if (head.bounds.overlaps(wall.bounds))
                head.dead();
        }
    }   
}
```

The TailSnake's code:

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class TailSnake {

    static final float SIZE = 0.1f;

    Vector2 position = new Vector2();
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();
    float lifeTime = 0;

    public TailSnake(Vector2 position) {
        this.position = position;
        this.bounds.height = SIZE;
        this.bounds.width = SIZE;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return bounds;
    }

    public Vector2 getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        lifeTime += delta;
    }
}
```

And finally the code of HeadSnake:

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class HeadSnake extends TailSnake{

    static final float SPEED = 1f;
    static final double ROTATE_SPEED = 200;

    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();
    Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();
    boolean alive = true;

    public HeadSnake(Vector2 position) {
        super(position);
        this.velocity.x = 0;
        this.velocity.y = SPEED;
    }

    public Vector2 getVelocity() {
        return velocity;
    }

    public boolean getAlive() {
        return alive;
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        if (alive)
            position.add(velocity.cpy().scl(delta));        
    }

    public void dead() {
        this.alive = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating the bounds. In your update method, after you set position, update the bounds as well. Something like-

```
bounds.x = position.x;
bounds.y = position.y;
bounds.x -= bounds.width / 2f;
bounds.y -= bounds.height / 2f;
```

Comment: Thank's a lot. I have no idea why I don't thought about this.